# Reemplazar valores de un Array desde otros Arrays en PHP

Tags: php

Necesito realizar un `array` que almacene valores de acuerdo a una comparación de arrays. Me explico:

Tengo un ArrayA

```
ArrayA = [1,1,0,2,0]//1 = Activo, 0= neutro, 2=desactivado
```

y otros Arrays que pueden ser varios. Por ejemplo:

```
ArrayB = [1,1,0,2,1]
ArrayC = [1,2,1,0,1]
ArrayD = [1,1,2,1,1]
Array...n
```

Estos se deben comparar uno tras otro iniciando con el `ArrayA y ArrayB` este genera un `Nuevo Array` y este se debe comparar con el `ArrayC` y así sucesivamente hasta generar un `Nuevo Array Final`.

La comparación es de la siguiente manera:

1. Si el indice del ArrayA es 1, el Array final es 1.
2. Si el indice del ArrayA es 2, el Array final es 2.
3. Si el indice del ArrayA es 0 y en algún Array B,C,D,N... es 2, el Array final es 2.
4. Si el indice del ArrayA es 0 y en todos los Array B,C,D,N... es 1, el Array final es 1.

El `ArrayFinal` con los Arrays A, B, C y D anteriores quedaría así `[1,1,2,2,1]`

Mi código:

```
                $data_user_valor=[1,1,0,2,0,1];
                $data_user_perfiles=['perfil1','perfil2']; //en este caso solo 2
                $data_final=array();

                $y=0;
                foreach ($data_user_perfiles as $user_perfiles)
                {
    //Mediante una query con el valor de $user_perfiles asigno valores al array data_perfiles_valor (query extensa por eso no la incluyo).

//Debe ser asi para obtener los valores de cada $user_perfiles

    //$data_perfiles_valor cambiara una vez que termine el proceso para el siguiente indice de $user_perfiles.

                    $data_perfiles_valor=[1,1,0,2];

    //Aquí estoy tratando de asignar y comparar los valores al Array Final
                    while($y<=4)
                    {
                        if($data_user_valor[$y][valor] == 1 )
                        {
                            array_push($data_final,1);
                        }
                        elseif ($data_user_valor[$y][valor] == 2 ) {
                            array_push($data_final,2);
                        }
                        elseif ($data_user_valor[$y][valor] == 0 && $data_perfiles_valor[$y][valor] == 1) {
                            array_push($data_final,1);
                        }
                        elseif ($data_user_valor[$y][valor] == 0 && $data_perfiles_valor[$y][valor] == 2) {
                            array_push($data_final,2);
                        }
                        else {
                            array_push($data_privileges,0);
                        }
                        $y++;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los arrays son de una sola dimension, por lo que no necesitas el segundo indice `valor`.  Tampoco necesitas la condicion de chequear si el valor es 0 porque si no lo fuera entraria a los primeros dos if.  Entonces quedaria asi:

```
$data_user_valor=[1,1,0,2,0,1];
            $data_user_perfiles=['perfil1','perfil2']; //en este caso solo 2
            $data_final=array();


            foreach ($data_user_perfiles as $user_perfiles)
            {
                 $y=0;
//Mediante una query con el valor de $user_perfiles asigno valores al array data_perfiles_valor (query extensa por eso no la incluyo).

//Debe ser asi para obtener los valores de cada $user_perfiles

//$data_perfiles_valor cambiara una vez que termine el proceso para el siguiente indice de $user_perfiles.

                $data_perfiles_valor=[1,1,0,2,1];

//Aquí estoy tratando de asignar y comparar los valores al Array Final
                while($y<=4)
                {
                    if($data_user_valor[$y] == 1 )
                    {
                        array_push($data_final,1);
                    }
                    elseif ($data_user_valor[$y] == 2 ) {
                        array_push($data_final,2);
                    }
                    elseif ($data_perfiles_valor[$y] == 1) {
                        array_push($data_final,1);
                    }
                    elseif ($data_perfiles_valor[$y][valor] == 2) {
                        array_push($data_final,2);
                    }
                    else {
                        array_push($data_privileges,0);
                    }
                    $y++;
            }
```